# Thinkpad Hardware problem after 14.04 regular Update

Tags: 14.04, wireless, upgrade, hardware

I run Ubuntu 14.04 on a T430 ThinkPad.

After a automated update some of my hardware was not working any more:

1) external mouse 2) external keyboard 3) external screen 4) wireless

I have run the following set of commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade
```

and got the following message:

```
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-68-generic (--configure):
package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-68-generic is not ready for configuration
cannot configure (current status `half-installed')
Errors were encountered while processing:
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-68-generic

N: Ignoring file '20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

In turn I made a backup of the file 20 auto... and subsequently deleted it and again:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade
```

Now it is not showing any problems that I can see.

However the Thinkpad hardware is still not working.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You provide very little information on what exactly went wrong during the upgrade (power loss? Hard shutdown?) so now just reboot into the previous kernel and do another

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and let it finish normally...

Comment: Hello fabby, thanks a lot for your quick reply.

Comment: I went to the previous kernel version and it works now.  I also run sudo apt-get dist-upgrade. Do I have to remove the broken Kernel?

Comment: Don't thank me!  **;-)** If this answer did help, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey ☑ *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, just [ask another one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)!  **:-)**